# Load NSMenu from nib for NSPanel

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsmenu

I am showing a floating `NSPanel` (separate from the main application window) for inputing data (I should add, this is a UIElement application but not a background one, i.e. it has no main window per say, and responds to global keyboard shortcuts to launch a window). I want certain keyboard shortcuts to work specifically for this `NSPanel` in addition to the ones the main menu supports for the application window.

How can I set a NSMenu for the floating panel such that keyboard shortcuts are sent to this panel when it's a `keyWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution was to simply implement the menu actions in the NSViewController hosted by the panel. This would then get picked up in the responder chain for all keyboard shortcuts supported.